# Protractor ignoreSynchronization issue

Tags: protractor, angularjs-e2e, e2e-testing

I am developing the e2e test suite for one of my applications. We have a sso that is a non angular site, our site is an angular site. in the start of my test i make a call to SSO settings:

```
 browser.ignoreSynchronization = true;        
 browser.get(browser.baseUrl + '/agoda/home?mock=mock-jax);
```

I am able to log on sucessfully and it redirects to my application which is an angular site. I set **browser.ignoreSynchronization = false**; as soon as i redirect to my application and its loaded. After this nothing works.

I try to read following:

```
var books= element.all(by.repeater('book in books'));
console.log(licenses.count());
```

results into

```
{ ptor_:
   { controlFlow: [Function],
     schedule: [Function],
     setFileDetector: [Function],
     getSession: [Function],
     getCapabilities: [Function],
     quit: [Function],
     actions: [Function],
     touchActions: [Function],
     executeScript: [Function],
     executeAsyncScript: [Function],
     call: [Function],
     wait: [Function],
     sleep: [Function],
     getWindowHandle: [Function],
     getAllWindowHandles: [Function],
     getPageSource: [Function],
     close: [Function],
     getCurrentUrl: [Function],
     getTitle: [Function],
     findElementInternal_: [Function],
     findDomElement_: [Function],
     findElementsInternal_: [Function],
     takeScreenshot: [Function],
..
}
```

I believe this has something to do with the ignoreSynchronization but not sure what i am doing wrong?

Comment: Please read console.log(licenses.count()); as console.log(books.count());

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not catching the promise that the `count()` function returns as a callback after its execution. Protractor is built on WebDriverJs model of async with promises. It has nothing to do with your `ignoreSynchronization` and you are console logging a protractor instance object instead of its value. You need to console log the value that is returned through the promise. Here's how -

```
var books= element.all(by.repeater('book in books'));
books.count().then(function(booksCount){
    console.log(booksCount);
});
```

The above way of using `.then()` in above code should solve your problem. [More about promises](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/WebDriverJs#Promises). Hope it helps.